# How to get an array of posts ids in types_child_posts?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, session

```
<?php $session = types_child_posts("child");?>
<?php foreach ($session as $session_posts):?>
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['posts'] = "$session_posts->ID"; echo $_SESSION['posts']?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to send posts IDs as array to session, but in this case I received a space separated numbers.
How to translate it to array ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $explodedPostIds = explode(' ', $yourPostIDs); ?>
```

You can just explode them by the space.

Like this you always create a new array index when the function reaches a space ' '

Comment: It doesn't seems to work. As a result I have Array Array

Comment: @user3300857 Then you have to show your data once, and what you expect

Comment: @user3300857 You have an array inside an array when you explode it by space? Then you definetly dont get space seperated numbers :)